# Wow6432Node AddIn HKLM Registry path duplication

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, add-in

Utility under discussion: Microsoft word 2010 add in using .Net3.5

Target platform Windows Server 2008 R2, Microsoft Office 2010 professional 32 bit

In Visual studio setup project i add registry enftries in HKCU as well as in HKLM. As per my research Addin to be made available to all users registry has to be added in

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\myaddin.

but when i install my addin on target machine HKCU entries are correcrt so administrator can use the installed addin but for HKLM it becomes

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\myaddin

so when users logg in through AD they dont see the add in. every time i have to manually write enties in

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\myaddin

through server administrator account. Why is extra Wow6432Node added after Wow6432Node

please guide what am i missing.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to add "Wow6432Node", it is handled automatically by the system, depending on your setup type (x86/x64). In particular, depending on whether the component in setup is x86 or x64.

Visual studio generates x86 setup, this this node should be added automatically.

Try simply removing this "Wow6432Node" part.